# event dispatched won’t receive in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I created an event:

```
package  {
    import flash.events.Event;
    public class TimeOutEvent extends Event{
        public static const TIMEOUT:String = "timeOut";
        public function TimeOutEvent(
            type:String=TIMEOUT,bubbles:Boolean=true, cancelable:Boolean=false
        ){
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        }   
        public override function clone():Event{
            return new TimeOutEvent(type,bubbles, cancelable);
        }
    }
}
```

And dispatched it on another class:

```
dispatchEvent( new TimeOutEvent(TimeOutEvent.TIMEOUT));
```

both of this two class are in dashboard.swf file, and I listen to this event in another swf file (main.swf):

```
addEventListener("timeOut",timeOut);

public function timeOut(e:Event):void{
    trace(“horaaaaa”);
}
```

I loaded and got instance from dashboard.swf in mail.swf
It is ok and work when I run it from adobe flash professional, but won’t work when I open it from browser.

any idea !!??
thanks for your help, sorry for very poor language.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to do some small changes in your TimeOutEvent class and the way how I added the eventListener. I tested and works fine.

Follow my changes:

```
// TimeOutEvent.as
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class TimeOutEvent extends Event
    {
         public static const TIME_OUT:String = 'timeOut';

         public function TimeOutEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false)
         {
             super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
         }

         override public function clone():Event
         {
             return new TimeOutEvent(type, bubbles, cancelable);
         }
    }
}

// Main.as

addEventListener(TimeOutEvent.TIME_OUT, timeOutHandler);

dispatchEvent(new TimeOutEvent(TimeOutEvent.TIME_OUT));


private function timeOutHandler(event:TimeOutEvent):void
{
    trace('horaaaaa');
}
```

Comment: No, it was not work!
Do you put dispatch code and listen code in two different project? I think problem is where event should dispatch form one project or swf file and should listen form another swf file.

Comment: if you have access to the TimeOutEvent class (importing the respective class), you will be able to make it work. If you are dispatching from one project that doesn't have access to this class, it will not work, for sure.

Comment: yes, i have access to TimeOutEvent class, as I said it works fine in windows flash palayer but won't work in browser. and I need it in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Running your code in Flash Pro is equivalent to running your code as a Windows AIR application. However, running in the browser is a very different thing. It could be some runtime limitations in the browser that are thwarting your efforts to communication in-between SWF files.